# How to execute a script(say python or java etc) based on the value of the property in Apache NiFi

Tags: python-3.x, apache-nifi

I have a flow file containing key value pairs, will read from Kafka and send to Nifi, using Getfile I will receive the file and then using Configure Process we can extract the contents of flowfile and keep them as flowfile attributes by adding matching regex.

Now after that I need to use specific attribute(s)(which I have got in the above step) and its value(s) and compare with the particular string value or will read the corresponding property value from nifi.properties file or custom properties file.

Now based on the validity I need to execute a script using ExecuteStream Command, suppose the extracted attribute value and nifi.properties or custom properties value matches then i should execute the script.
Here the query is how to compare the property values and execute the script.

Comment: did you try using `RouteOnAttribute (matched property/attribute value) => ExecuteStreamCommand`

Comment: Yes, my issue is working after using RouteOnAttribute